# Visual Studio Output Window does not update

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, output

The output window in Visual Studio does not seem to be updating. When I manually switch the "Show output from" to any other option, then back to "Debug" it refreshes but otherwise, it does not refresh on its own. Does anyone know why this is occurring.

The commands `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` and `SystemDiagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()` both result in the same problem.

Comment: I had a problem like this that turned out to be an VS addon. If you have any addons, try disabling them then restart VS and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with Application.DoEvents();

Putting this immediately after your .WriteLines(); will allow the program to dispatch window events, otherwise you're simply going to see 'Not Responding' at the top of the screen.  However, if you're displaying something in the interior of a detail loop, this will slow things down a lot.  When it repaints the Trace screen, it's refreshing the entire window, not simply the line you just wrote.